# Arduino nano : Memory stability issue

Tags: c, arduino

Currently, I'm working with **Arduino nano**. When I compile my `c` code in Arduino IDE, I got below error.

[image]

program uploading successfully and working fine, Then whats the reason behind this error? Is it really affect the performance of arduino nano?

Comment: Compiler cannot know the space local variables, function parameters and return addresses on the stack will need at runtime. Those will interfere with global variables without any mercy, if space is not sufficient. Producing completely unpredictable results.

Comment: that is a warning about the 'probability' of not having enough space (mostly not enough stack space) for the program to run properly,  You can greatly assist the program to run properly by creating a software architecture that is very wide, rather than very deep.

Answer (score 2):

This warning occur because the compiler does not know how much dynamic memory should be allocated by your program. Please look at your program at Dynamic Allocation, Local Variable Allocation...

> Is it really affect the performance of arduino nano?

Like it said *"stability problems may occur"*. I did face this in the past and the project run with lag sometime.

Answer (score 1):

```
int freeRam () {
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval;
  int v;
  return (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval);
}
```

call this function e.g.

```
 Serial.println(freeRam());
```

at the deepest level of your functions or wherever you want.

And don't use malloc() or c++ new, to avoid "stability problems", because there's no exception handling or other error checking in dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it really affect the performance of arduino nano?

I also got the **same error while compiling**, **its a warning** as you said ur uploading done successfully, If uploading done successful then there is no performance issue. if you want to clear this error you need to **reduce some memory usage of your code,** 
just Optimize your code, use local variables as much as possible. also if you have constants, use `#define` instead,
group repetitive calls into a function.

Comment: Usually, the **F**- macro removes most of unnecessary RAM spoiling. **Serial.println(F("any constant text can be kept out of precious RAM"));**

Comment: Not to forget String objects, which need more space and use dynamic memory, thus combining two reasons for instability.

Comment: > _if you have constants, use #define instead_ ...or use the **const** keyword. Similar optimization effect, but **const** preserves data type information.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it is just a warning, but you may get erratic behaviour depending actual memory use.

I a small project I made recently (https://releasetheinnergeek.wordpress.com/2018/05/16/minimalist-lidar/), depending on how much dynamic memory was left, different behaviours were observed, such as: servo not operating, screen not displaying correctly and/or inacurate laser readings.

You get the warning from 70% use onwards. The actual behaviour depends.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "perfomance" on microcontrollers: it always executes the flashed assembler instructions with the system clock frequency. It happens the following way: the first byte (which is always instruction) is shifted to the CPU and processed as instruction; the next byte could be data byte or next instruction byte (depending on the first instruction), and so on. So there is no difference or special "mark" for bytes to be command or data. When the properly compiled and flashed program works the CPU always interprets all the command bytes as command and all the data bytes as data because all of them come in the right order.

The address of the current program byte that is going to be shifted is stored in the Program Counter register which value increments by one with every executed instruction.

For now, let's have a look to the standart memory map of the AVR microcontrollers used by avr-gcc compiler:

[image: RAM map]

There is data put on .data variables and .bss variables sections that is known while compiling the program. It is reffered as "global variables" on Arduino IDE log. When your program dynamically allocate memory, it is put into the heap section, while local variables used by functions and some registers values are placed to the stack section. Everything works well only if heap and stack sections do not collide to each other (that is, if there is enough free RAM).

What could go wrong if there is no free RAM left?

Just one example with the assumption that free RAM is over:

1. Program executes some function. This is done with the use of `jmp` instruction.
2. Just before jumping to the program address of the function, the current value of the Program Counter (PC) is stored in stack. When function completes execution, PC value from stack is used to restore the position of the currently running program and resume execution from the point just after the function call.
3. Function allocates some data in heap section, but there is no free RAM left, so the data rewrites the previously stored Program Counter value.
4. The function ends with `ret` instruction. The value of the Program Counter is restored but at the moment it points to the wrong location, that could be not just wrong instruction but even data.
5. At that point CPU interprets the data as command and the subsequent behaviour becomes unpredictable.

Low free memory issue is not an error on its own, but could be the reason of unpredictable behaviour and stability problems. Just follow the advises of the other commentors to prevent such issues.

In fact, if you do everything right, your program can be stable even with very little free RAM.